# Why is x==x false if the value of x is NaN?

Tags: c

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

This specifies that x==x is false if x is NaN. 
What would be the underlying reason? If the compiler detects stuff like 1.0/0.0 (NaN) wouldn't it automatically set the value to 0x7F800000 (IEEE754 Single Precision Floating Point representation for NaN/Inf). Then when the x==x comparison occurs, should it be true as it would be a comparison of the same hex value?

Comment: I believe `==` can only compare two "numbers".

Comment: The conceptual reason I've understood is that NaN is never equal to anything, even to itself.

Comment: Dividing by zero results in floating point exception (FPE). You shuold use `isnan()` and `isinf()` unfctions instead.

Comment: `log(0) == NaN`.  `0/0 == NaN`.  That doesn't mean that `log(0) == 0/0`.

Comment: This is not a C question in that C does not define what should happen with  `x==x false if the value of x is NaN`.  Many C platforms follow IEEE754 on this matter, so it is a IEEE754 one.

Comment: Just to enforce that once you have NaN as an intermediate result, you can never be able to return to the real side of things. Safety measure. And: THOU SHALT NEVER COMPARE FP VALUES USING ==

Comment: @tofro: Relax. Sometimes it's useful to compare floating point values with `==`.

Comment: Really? Give me an example, please.

Comment: @tofro: `if (x + K - K == x)`, where `K` is a properly chosen power of 2, to determine if `x` has any bits past a given precision.

Comment: Alright. Maybe also to find out whether two doubles were created using the very same calculations. Bought, but only accepted as *very sometimes*